# SQL server 2008 Computed Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is my formula in the computer column specification in a table called Loan

```
(dateadd(month,(1),[CheckOutDate]))
```

The (1) should be replaced by `loan_period` from another table called `item_details`.

Is that possible and how would the formula look.

Comment: You'll need to create a UDF for this -- what is the relationship between the two tables?

Comment: If you need this field to be calculated, I would create a db function and use a trigger to update the field when a new record is inserted or if need be, updated. [MS SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

Comment: @sgeddes OK thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 2):

[Computed columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) only refer to columns in the same table, as far as I'm aware.

To do what you want here, you can either define a `TRIGGER` on both tables that will populate the data when either table is modified, or (easier) create a `VIEW`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a computed column that uses a function that then refers to a another table.

E.g.

```
create table t (
    a int primary key,
    b int
)
GO

create function dbo.f(@a int)
returns int
as
begin
    return (select b from t where a = @a);
end
GO

create table t2 (
    c int primary key,
    d as dbo.f(c)
)
GO

insert into t values (1, 2)
insert into t2 (c) values (1)

select * from t2
```

N.B. You should consider performance considerations when doing this, and ensure that at least you have the right indexes in place.